# Decode JSON with multiple group values in Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, web-services

I'm getting values from my web server from Swift through `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error)` the output I get is something like:

```
(
    {
    ANO = 2017;
    CLAVESSAMEDICAMENTO = "010.000.0101.00";
    CLUES = BSSSA000035;
    CONSUMOPROMEDIOMENSUAL = 87;
    DESCRIPCIONMEDICAMENTO = "\U00c1CIDO ACETILSALIC\U00cdLICO TABLETAS";
    MES = 01;
    MUNICIPIO = "Comond\U00fa";
    NOMBREUNIDAD = "C.S.U. CIUDAD CONSTITUCION";
    PRESENTACION = "ENVASE CON 20 TABLETAS";
    RECETADOMENSUAL = 280;
    SURTIDOMENSUAL = 252;
    id = 1867;
},
    {
    ANO = 2017;
    CLAVESSAMEDICAMENTO = "010.000.0103.00";
    CLUES = BSSSA000035;
    CONSUMOPROMEDIOMENSUAL = 70;
    DESCRIPCIONMEDICAMENTO = "ACIDO ACETILSALICILICO TABLETA SOLUBLE";
    MES = 01;
    MUNICIPIO = "Comond\U00fa";
    NOMBREUNIDAD = "C.S.U. CIUDAD CONSTITUCION";
    PRESENTACION = "ENVASE CON 20 TABLETAS";
    RECETADOMENSUAL = 240;
    SURTIDOMENSUAL = 216;
    id = 1879;
},
    {
    ANO = 2017;
    CLAVESSAMEDICAMENTO = "010.000.0104.00";
    CLUES = BSSSA000035;
    CONSUMOPROMEDIOMENSUAL = 42;
    DESCRIPCIONMEDICAMENTO = "PARACETAMOL TABLETA";
    MES = 01;
    MUNICIPIO = "Comond\U00fa";
    NOMBREUNIDAD = "C.S.U. CIUDAD CONSTITUCION";
    PRESENTACION = "ENVASE CON 10 TABLETAS";
    RECETADOMENSUAL = 743;
    SURTIDOMENSUAL = 669;
    id = 1891;
},
    {...
```

And I'm trying to decode it in a class so I can access it values. My class is:

```
struct Informacion: Codable {
    let id: String
    let clues: String
    let nombreunidad: String
    let municipio: String
    let clavesmedicamentos: String
    let descripcionmedicamentos: String
    let presentacion: String
    let consumopromediomensual: Int
    let recetadomensual: Int
    let surtidomensual: Int
    let mes: String
    let ano: String
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case clues = "CLUES"
        case nombreunidad = "NOMBREUNIDAD"
        case municipio = "MUNICIPIO"
        case clavesmedicamentos = "CLAVESSAMEDICAMENTO"
        case descripcionmedicamentos = "DESCRIPCIONMEDICAMENTO"
        case presentacion = "PRESENTACION"
        case consumopromediomensual = "CONSUMOPROMEDIOMENSUAL"
        case recetadomensual = "RECETADOMENSUAL"
        case surtidomensual = "SURTIDOMENSUAL"
        case mes = "MES"
        case ano = "ANO"
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to decode the JSON values to fit in my class. I tried to make another class with a single value as an array from the other class, something like:

```
struct Unidades_Informacion: Codable {
    let valores: Array<Informacion>
}
```

But I get:

> Thread 6: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear it's an array , you can try

```
do {
     let arr = try JSONDecoder().decode([Informacion].self,data)
 }
 catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Remove struct `Unidades_Informacion` it has no relation to this json , This is an array

```
[{},{},{}]    // (2) but you have this
```

While this is a dictionary

```
{"valores": [{},{},{}]}   /// (1) you attempt with this
```

Comment: Thanks it totally works, I do not know why I thought it was a dictionary when it clearly was an array.